# warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I am getting this warning with below piece of initialization code.

```
const uint16_t macaddr_reg[] = {0x2006, 0x2007, 0x2008, 0x2009, 0x2000A, 0x200B };
```

However below code gives no warning

```
const uint16_t tmp = 0x2006;
```

Please let me know where am I wrong? I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: The 5th (2nd to last) number is to big for 16bit. Though I do not know why this error.

Answer (score 3):

It was a typo mistake. Corrected it.
Notice **0x2000A** in initialization. It is not 16 bit.